# Ogre 3D load models created with Easy Ogre Exporter

Tags: c++, ogre, ogre3d

I'm currently trying to export a .max file to .mesh and it success.
The problem is that I don't have any color on my form (it's a basic cylinder actually).

Easy Ogre Exporter gave me several more files like .scene .material .cg .program. I tried to set this .material to .mesh entity but it's still white.

Please help me, I really searched on the web but found nothing working.

Best regards,

Coucka

Comment: Cross-post: http://www.ogre3d.org/forums/viewtopic.php?f=2&t=80368

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If Ogre encounters an issue with your materials / shaders / textures, it usually falls back to a material called "*BaseWhite*", which might be what you are experiencing.

1. First step: Check the *Ogre.log* file to see if the **.material* file was loaded at all and if there were any error while parsing it. You should find an entry similar to this one:

   > 23:45:10: Parsing script Test.material
2. If your material is also using the shader that was written into the **.cg shader* file, check that it is loaded as well without any errors, plus check that a valid shader profile was used, that your hardware supports (otherwise you will find a note in the log, telling you that no supported profile was found). The supported shader profiles will also the output into the log file, like so:

   > 23:45:10:  * Supported Shader Profiles: hlsl ps_1_1 ps_1_2 ps_1_3 ps_1_4 ps_2_0 ps_2_a ps_2_b ps_2_x ps_3_0 vs_1_1 vs_2_0 vs_2_a vs_2_x vs_3_0
3. If you are using textures on your model, make sure that the needed texture files can be found by Ogre. To do so verify that all paths from where Ogre should load resources are listed in the configuration file *resources.cfg*. Also for textures to work, your model of course needs to have exported UV coordinates. If the texture was successfully loaded, the following entry should appear in the log (the types and formats of course could be different):

   > 23:45:10: Texture: Texture.jpg: Loading 1 faces(PF_R8G8B8,256x256x1) Internal format is PF_X8R8G8B8,256x256x1.